# If cell contains only specific info and nothing else

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to write a formula where it only gives an answer if the cell contains ONLY the info written in the code.

This is the code:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim rcell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("G2:G" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each rcell In rng.Cells

Group = ""
G1 = 0
G2 = 0

valuesA = Split(Range(rcell.Address), ",")

For Each Value In valuesA

Select Case Value
    Case "2528", "2529", "2530", "2531", "2532", "2533", "2534", "2535", "2536", "2537"
    G1 = G1 + 1

    Case "2549", "2550", "2551", "2553", "2555", "2556", "2557", "2558", "2561", "2567"
    G2 = G2 + 1
End Select

Next

If rng.Value = G1 Or rng.Value = G2 And InStr(1, rng.Value, "601"  Then
rcell.Offset(, 4).Value = ""
Else: rcell.Offset(, 4).Value = "601"
End If
```

I used this code where it will add **601** to 4th cell if it contains one of the codes in the groups. **But** if the cell contains anything else than those codes, it should not add 601 in the 4th cell. I tried another formula given in this forum which deletes the codes which aren't in the given groups, but that doesn't work either.

**UPDATE**

For example:

Cell G2 = **111,601,2528,2533,2552**

Because **111** is in the cell, **601** has to stay. 111 is one of the numbers but there are like 1000 numbers like that, such as **14,39,63**. If it does not contain those numbers, 601 has to be removed. I hope that I explained it well.

Comment: When you refer to formula presumably you mean code? You can't compare a multi-cell range to a single value, you have to loop through it. The code you've posted doesn't seem to relate to your question very closely.

Comment: Maybe it's good to show some sample data, sample output along with a good explanation.

Comment: More accurately, your code does not do what you say in your description "add 601 to 4th cell if it contains one of the codes in the groups".

Comment: @SJR I edited my question to clarify the situation. I hope you could help me out.

Comment: How does the code you've posted relate to your question?